# pureconfig is not parsing boolean value Scala CovertFailure(WrongType(String, Set(Boolean)))

Tags: scala, implicit, pureconfig

In my app.config file there is a property like:

```
enable-toggle-prop {
   update-toggle-enabled=false
}
```

The file where I am parsing looks like this:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

case class MyConfig(updateToggleEnabled: Boolean)
object MyConfig {
    val config: MyConfig = {
        val parseConfig = ConfigSource.default.at("enable-toggle-prop").load[MyConfig]
    config match {
       case Left(error) => //Throwing Illegal Argument exception
       case Right(parsedConf) => parsedConf
    }
}
```

When I am trying to deploy the app I am running into IllegalArgumentException saying "Configuration is Invalid: ConfigReaderFailure(CovertFailure(WrongType(String, Set(Boolean))))..."
Why is it not able to convert Boolean? Is there anything I am missing here? TIA

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/wYoQ6OMxQbywstYgGXH47g - Thus, your real code may have a problem elsewhere, try to modify the **Scastie** until you can reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks @Luis, I have updated the Scastie with the issue I am currently facing.

Comment: When you edit the **Scastie** it creates a new link, so please edit your question with the new link.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8ydk2UNXTFmSsA1xHJdKDg

Comment: Well, of course trying to call `default` on **Scastie** will not work, there are no resource files in **Scastie**, that is why my example has a hardcoded string literal and uses that as the config. - You have not reproduced the problem in any way.